# subset data frame for the last week data

Tags: r

I have a time series data frame like below. I would like to subset this data for the last week Sunday-Saturday day. Is there a known function to calculate the last week, regardless of when the function is ran?

```
   dput(head(y,100))
structure(list(DATE = structure(c(15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 15809, 
15809, 15809, 15810, 15810, 15810, 15810), class = "Date"), Time = structure(c(1365984840, 
1365985740, 1365986640, 1365987540, 1365988440, 1365989340, 1365990240, 
1365991140, 1365992040, 1365992940, 1365993840, 1365994740, 1365995640, 
1365996540, 1365997440, 1365998340, 1365912840, 1365913740, 1365914640, 
1365915540, 1365916440, 1365917340, 1365918240, 1365919140, 1365920040, 
1365920940, 1365921840, 1365922740, 1365923640, 1365924540, 1365925440, 
1365926340, 1365927240, 1365928140, 1365929040, 1365929940, 1365930840, 
1365931740, 1365932640, 1365933540, 1365934440, 1365935340, 1365936240, 
1365937140, 1365938040, 1365938940, 1365939840, 1365940740, 1365941640, 
1365942540, 1365943440, 1365944340, 1365945240, 1365946140, 1365947040, 
1365947940, 1365948840, 1365949740, 1365950640, 1365951540, 1365952440, 
1365953340, 1365954240, 1365955140, 1365956040, 1365956940, 1365957840, 
1365958740, 1365959640, 1365960540, 1365961440, 1365962340, 1365963240, 
1365964140, 1365965040, 1365965940, 1365966840, 1365967740, 1365968640, 
1365969540, 1365970440, 1365971340, 1365972240, 1365973140, 1365974040, 
1365974940, 1365975840, 1365976740, 1365977640, 1365978540, 1365979440, 
1365980340, 1365981240, 1365982140, 1365983040, 1365983940, 1366071240, 
1366072140, 1366073040, 1366073940), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), CPU = c(30.4333333333333, 30.0666666666667, 29.9666666666667, 
31.0333333333333, 29.9666666666667, 27.0333333333333, 24.6, 23.1666666666667, 
24.5, 21.8, 20.1333333333333, 20.6333333333333, 22.4, 20.8333333333333, 
20.2333333333333, 19.7333333333333, 20.2857142857143, 15.4, 17.1666666666667, 
14.6333333333333, 20, 15.8666666666667, 14.6, 16.0333333333333, 
15, 13.9666666666667, 13.7, 11.3666666666667, 11.6666666666667, 
10.5666666666667, 19.2333333333333, 21.6, 21.9666666666667, 21.1, 
18.8666666666667, 20.5, 19.7666666666667, 17.1666666666667, 15.6333333333333, 
10.2666666666667, 9.33333333333333, 8.73333333333333, 9.4, 10, 
12.2333333333333, 12.8666666666667, 13.6333333333333, 14.4333333333333, 
15.6666666666667, 15.6666666666667, 16.6, 17.9333333333333, 20.0666666666667, 
20.2, 21.4666666666667, 22.4333333333333, 25.0333333333333, 24.6, 
25.0333333333333, 25.8666666666667, 25.9666666666667, 21.2, 23.2333333333333, 
30.2758620689655, 30.3666666666667, 29.5666666666667, 29, 29.9666666666667, 
30.0666666666667, 29.8666666666667, 28.8333333333333, 29, 29.5, 
29.4, 28.9333333333333, 28.5, 28.4, 29.3, 27.1666666666667, 26.7, 
27.5333333333333, 27.3333333333333, 26.6333333333333, 26.8333333333333, 
26.9, 26.4666666666667, 26.1, 26.0333333333333, 26.4, 26.4333333333333, 
25.8, 25.7666666666667, 32.4333333333333, 26.6666666666667, 25.7333333333333, 
26.8333333333333, 39.4666666666667, 34.2666666666667, 29.3333333333333, 
28.2666666666667), Time1 = c("20:14", "20:29", "20:44", "20:59", 
"21:14", "21:29", "21:44", "21:59", "22:14", "22:29", "22:44", 
"22:59", "23:14", "23:29", "23:44", "23:59", "00:14", "00:29", 
"00:44", "00:59", "01:14", "01:29", "01:44", "01:59", "02:14", 
"02:29", "02:44", "02:59", "03:14", "03:29", "03:44", "03:59", 
"04:14", "04:29", "04:44", "04:59", "05:14", "05:29", "05:44", 
"05:59", "06:14", "06:29", "06:44", "06:59", "07:14", "07:29", 
"07:44", "07:59", "08:14", "08:29", "08:44", "08:59", "09:14", 
"09:29", "09:44", "09:59", "10:14", "10:29", "10:44", "10:59", 
"11:14", "11:29", "11:44", "11:59", "12:14", "12:29", "12:44", 
"12:59", "13:14", "13:29", "13:44", "13:59", "14:14", "14:29", 
"14:44", "14:59", "15:14", "15:29", "15:44", "15:59", "16:14", 
"16:29", "16:44", "16:59", "17:14", "17:29", "17:44", "17:59", 
"18:14", "18:29", "18:44", "18:59", "19:14", "19:29", "19:44", 
"19:59", "20:14", "20:29", "20:44", "20:59")), .Names = c("DATE", 
"Time", "CPU", "Time1"), row.names = 4205:4304, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(chron) # for is.weekend

x[as.numeric(strftime(x$Time,format="%W")) ==
    as.numeric(strftime(Sys.time(),format="%W")) - 1 & is.weekend(x$Time),]
```

I have assumed that even if today is Saturday (or Sunday) the code needs to select the previous weekend anyway.

EDIT: this is a time zone issue (I'm two hours before you), so the following are sounday late evenings for me. But for you it's correct that you get nothing, cause no rows is at same a weekend and in the previous week. The only one is the 14th (Sunday) but it is two weeks ago.

```
> x[as.numeric(strftime(x$Time,format="%W")) ==
+     as.numeric(strftime(Sys.time(),format="%W")) - 1 & is.weekend(x$Time),]
           DATE                Time      CPU Time1
4293 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 00:14:00 26.40000 18:14
4294 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 00:29:00 26.43333 18:29
4295 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 00:44:00 25.80000 18:44
4296 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 00:59:00 25.76667 18:59
4297 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 01:14:00 32.43333 19:14
4298 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 01:29:00 26.66667 19:29
4299 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 01:44:00 25.73333 19:44
4300 2013-04-14 2013-04-15 01:59:00 26.83333 19:59
```

Comment: @user1471980 Sorry before I forgot to specify the library.

Comment: I accepted the answer, but this is not working for me. I get empty data frame.

Comment: @user1471980 In this case that means that in your data there aren't rows whose `Time` value is a weekend of the previous week. e.g. is you run it now, in order to have a non empty data frame, in the `Time` column there should be `"2013-04-20"` or `"2013-04-21"`. Are you saying that there are such dates but they are not picked up?

Comment: yes, I do have 20th and 21st in my data frame and not picking it up.

Comment: @user1471980 I have just posted my result, and it is as expected. Could edit your question with the precise steps you've just done, we'll find the reason this way.

Comment: I attached the data from last week.

Comment: I got it, you are two hours ahead. Please check the result in the unswer. Basically, when I run the script I get the 8 rows that have "2013-04-15" and a time between midnight and 1:59 AM. I am in London so for is.weekend() they are "2013-04-14" just before midnight (so Sunday!). The issue is that strftime and is.weekend work differently with time zone.

Comment: I am running your exact line of code, I get nothing. I get an empty data frame.

Comment: rather than using x$Time, I used x$DATE and it worked. x$DATE is as.Date format and x$Time is as.POSIXct format.